# Java Card JCA file to CAP file name

Tags: java, applet, smartcard, javacard, apdu

Converting hello.jca file to hello.cap file using

```
./capgen.bat ".\hello.jca" -o ".\hello.cap"
```

output file is always a.jar even though I'm specifying the output file name.

Comment: Have you tried to put `".\hello.jca"` at the end? It is options, then filename.

Comment: Yes I tried that but still it's a.jar

Answer (score 0):

There is one way you can do that by using the `-config params.json` attribute of the `capgen.bat` tool.

However, you have to download and use `capgen.bat` file of at least `3.1.0` version, as even `3.0.5` doesn't have the mentioned attribute (see below). This can be achieved by download the [3.1.0 version of JavaCard Development Kit Tools](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javacard-sdk-downloads.html) namely the **`java_card_tools-win-bin-b_17-06_jul_2021.zip`** file.

Proof (`3.0.5` version)

```
PS C:\Users\pc> capgen.bat -version
CapGen [v3.0.5]
    Copyright (c) 1998, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\pc> capgen.bat -help

usage: capgen [-options] filename
where options include:

-help           Print this message and exit.
-nobanner       Do not display informational messages.
-o <filename>   Output filename. default: a.jar
-version        Print version number and exit.
```

Proof (`3.1.0` version)

```
PS C:\Users\pc> C:\development\code\java_card_tools-win-bin-b_17-06_jul_2021\bin\capgen.bat -version
CapGen [v3.1.0]
    Copyright (c) 1998, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\pc> C:\development\code\java_card_tools-win-bin-b_17-06_jul_2021\bin\capgen.bat -help

usage: capgen [-options] filename
where options include:
-help           Print this message and exit.
-nobanner       Do not display informational messages.
-o <filename>   Output filename. default: a.jar
-version        Print version number and exit.
-config         Run capgen in extended mode. In this case the filename must have .json extension.
```

Now, here is how I set the `json` file:

```
{
    "inputConfig": {
        "CAP_AID": "01:02:03:04:05:10",
        "CAP_name": "helloworld",
        "CAP_version": "1.0",
        "outputDir": "output",
        "debug": true,
        "inputPackages": [{
            "jcainputfile": "helloworld.jca"
        }]
    }
}
```

And here is how I invoked the command:

```
C:\development\code\java_card_tools-win-bin-b_17-06_jul_2021\bin\capgen.bat -config .\jca-to-cap.json
```

The `helloworld.cap` file appears in the `.\output\helloworld\javacard` directory. You can play with `outputDir` option in the **json** file to change the destination folder.

Note: the **cap** file one gets this way weighs less than if use the "normal" way by using the `convert_applet.bat` file.